# Login form: no matter what it displays the message of "Username/Password combination incorrect"

Tags: php, html, mysql

So far I had made a home.html, which is the home page that has to links to the login.php and the register.php, I have the login.php and register.php. also I have the member.php which is the page that the users, if registered, are redirected to.

my purpose was for every user that have registered to be able to log in.
the registration page successfully redirects to the members.php page but im having trouble with matching if the username exists in the database and if it matches with the password...log in the user.
what it's doing is no matter what I put in the fields of username and password it displays the message of "Username/Password combination incorrect".

this is my login.php code:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    //connect to database
    $db=mysqli_connect($host_name, $username, $password, $database);
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
         $username=($_POST['username']);
         $password=($_POST['password']);
         $password=md5($password);
         $sql="SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
         $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);

         if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){

             $_SESSION['message']="You are now Loggged In";
             $_SESSION['username']=$username;
             header("location:members.php");
             exit();
          }
         else{
            $_SESSION['message']="Username/Password combination incorrect";
                }
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: What a suprise, a school project where they don't teach about sql injection, how great! *Edit:* Even looked over the `md5()`, luckily the next generation is ready to get hacked!

Comment: Consider using PDO

Comment: This is 2017. Do people still use md5 for passwords?

Comment: @getl0st `mysqli_*` supports prepared statements, so no reason to go to `PDO`. The problem is with prepared statements, not the library.

Comment: What is `$result`?

Comment: Consider checking if password column size is enough and checking if you are actually registering a new user with md5, oc, this is just related to your specific problem. I'd consider checking what's been suggested in the comments.

Comment: First thing to do if this is what your school is teaching is to ask for a refund.

Comment: People should stop upvoting questions like these

Comment: this is a college board assignment that we are supposed to do without the help of a teacher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' and password = '$password'"
```

This works for me do not know why it does not for you guessing its your database setup rember this can be "hacked"